# Factory Boy test with Wagtail fails: TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got {}

Tags: django, wagtail, factory-boy

I'm trying to set up Factory Boy for a Wagtail site. In order for that to work, the _create method must be able to establish a parent-child-relationship between pages. I override the _create method as described in the docs: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#attributes-and-methods. But the addition of the 'parent' key causes the error.

Have been looking at it for ages, dug into the source files. I suspect it has to do with the way the model_class method passes the kwargs, but I guess I'm blind for any obvious mistakes by now. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

models.py:

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class HomePage(Page):
    pass

class SubjectPage(Page):
    pass
```

tests.py:

```
from .factories import HomePageFactory, SubjectPageFactory
from django.test import TestCase

class TestModels(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.homepage = HomePageFactory(title='Test page')
        cls.subjectpage = SubjectPageFactory(parent=cls.homepage)

    def test_dummy(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

factories.py:

```
import factory
from .models import HomePage, SubjectPage
from wagtail.core.models import Page


class PageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            parent = kwargs.pop('parent')
            page = model_class(*args, kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            parent = Page.get_first_root_node()
            page = model_class(*args, **kwargs)

        parent.add_child(instance=page)

        return page


class HomePageFactory(PageFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = HomePage


class SubjectPageFactory(PageFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = SubjectPage
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend `wagtail_factories` https://github.com/mvantellingen/wagtail-factories?

To set up:
`pip install wagtail-factories`

in `factories.py`

```
import wagtail_factories

from .models import HomePage, SubjectPage

class HomePageFactory(wagtail_factories.PageFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = HomePage

class SubjectPageFactory(wagtail_factories.PageFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = SubjectPage
```

in `tests.py`

```
from django.test import TestCase


class PagesTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_create(self):
        instance = HomePageFactory.create()
        self.assertIsNotNone(instance.pk)
```

If you want to test pages with some structure, the code below would create a homepage as a root of the site, and create a subject page as a child of the homepage.

```
from wagtail.core.models import Site
from .factories import HomePageFactory, SubjectPageFactory

class PageTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.homepage = HomePageFactory.create()
        self.site = Site.objects.all().first()
        self.site.root_page = self.homepage
        self.site.save()
        self.site.refresh_from_db()
        self.subject_page = SubjectPageFactory.create(parent=self.homepage)
```

Comment: I eventually got it working; it was a problem with the root of my site. I had already noticed wagtail_factories: excellent initiative! Your remark make me look into it better and I'll certainly consider using it when my tests get more complicated. Thanks!